# Logstash add field values

Tags: logstash, logstash-forwarder

I have a Logstash filter set which sets a field `Alert_level` to an integer based on regex matching the message.

Example:

```
if [message] =~ /(?i)foo/ {mutate {add_field => { "Alert_level" => "3" }}}
if [message] =~ /(?i)bar/ {mutate {add_field => { "Alert_level" => "2" }}}
```

These cases are not mutually exclusive and will sometimes result in events with 2 or more values in `Alert_level`:

```
message => "foobar"
Alert_level => "2, 3"
```

I want to add up the values in `Alert_level` to a total integer, where the above example would result in this:

```
message => "foobar"
Alert_level => "5"
```

Comment: You mean to have two conditions in an **if**?

Answer (score 1):

There is no math in logstash itself, but I like darth_vader's tag idea (if your levels are only hit once each).

You could set a tag for the alert levels, e.g. "alert_3", "alert_4", etc., and then drop into the ruby filter to loop across them, split out the numeric value, and add them together into a new field.  (Using a sentinel prefix like "alert_" will prevent you from trying to add a "_grokparsefailure" or other non-alert tag).

There are other examples on SO for looping across fields in ruby.

Answer (score -1):

As I understood your question, you need the *AND* operator within your **if** to check both the conditions:

```
if "foobar" in [message] and "5" in [Alert_level]{
   //do something
}
```

Comment: it work in this specific case. but i have more than 50+ lines like this =/

Comment: In that case, you have to identify another way to filter it out. Something like adding a *tag* if the alert level is so and so. What're you expecting from the conditional operator? To *filter* all the alert levels? And I don't see another work around for having multiple conditional statements unfortunately.

Comment: I don't think this is what OP was asking

Comment: @WillBarnwell So what do you think OP is asking?

Comment: I edited OP, he doesn't need help creating compound conditionals